# In karate framework, is it possible to include request/responses in junit reports

Tags: karate

I was wondering if it's possible to include requests/responses logs in the junit reports generated by karate.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not supported, and no support is planned. This is an area where the project invites open-source contributions.

Comment: Thanks Peter, and congratulations for this amazing framework :)